# Is it possible to customize j_security_check

Tags: java, security, java-ee-6, jdbcrealm

I am developing a web application using java EE technology. 
Currently i am developing the user registration function.
In this functionality I am sending an verification email to the user.
If user press the link which contains in the verification email; it will activate the user.

I want to prevent inactive user logins from the system.

But since i am using `jdbcrealm`; Currently I am troubling how to add this additional step to be perform in the login function.

Is there a way to edit or customize `j_security_check`.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree. Clicking the link in the verification email should activate the account, but there is no connection between that and `j_security_check`. If you're having a *specific* problem please describe it.

Comment: @EJP I want to allow login to the system for the users who enter a valid username and a password as well as who activate the account by pressing the verification link. How may i perform this task.

Comment: You don't have to allow a login for users who click the link. It's possible, but you have to write a Tomcat Valve to accomplish it, and it's non-trivial and Tomcat version dependent. Just make them login after the page where they click the link.